# What does aileron droop help to do?

Tags: aerodynamics

Aileron droop helps to:

A - prevent upfloat
B - correct adverse yaw
C - get control feel
D - compensate drag

Please mention the most appropriate choice and only one correct answer. With a brief explanation if possible!

Comment: Welcome to aviation.se! what do you need help with? why are you not able to choose the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your choices:

- a- prevent upfloat: droop is the reverse of upfloat. Upfloat is useful in reducing adverse yaw.
- b- correct adverse yaw: no, upfloat does that.
- c- get control feel: yes there might be some increased aeroforce feel gradient around neutral. Around zero deflection it takes a little while before the aerogradient picks up, creating very light forces in an area where good force feedback is important. Droop helps to reduce this, since both ailerons are sticking in the wind already.
- d- compensate drag: no, droop creates drag.